# Call jsp page from Liferay Portal

Tags: jsp, liferay, liferay-6

Im a newbie in Liferay development and I have a pretty simple question.

I have an example of portlet that shows a text message and I need to display in the Liferay Portal. How can I do this ? the JSP code is below:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %> 
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletPreferences" %> 

<portlet:defineObjects /> 

<% 
     PortletPreferences prefs = renderRequest.getPreferences();
     String greeting = (String)prefs.getValue( "greeting", "Hello! Welcome to our portal."); 
%>

<p><%= greeting %></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

> How can I write the same portlet without java code in view.jsp file?

You must override MVCPortlets **`doView`** method to initialize an attribute, let's consider the attribute **`greeting`**. For example:

```
public class Greeting extends MVCPortlet {

    @Override
    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {

        renderRequest.setAttribute("greeting", "Hello! Welcome to our portal.");

        super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }
}
```

And in your JSP file, retrieve the `greeting` attribute using EL `${greeting}`.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %> 

<portlet:defineObjects /> 

<p>${greeting}</p>
```

Ouput:

```
Hello! Welcome to our portal.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I meant something else. I'll try to explain better.

I have java file and I have view.jsp file with java code in it. How can I write the same portlet without java code in view.jsp file?

Comment: I edited the answer. You will see how to call Java code from jsp.

Comment: If I paste this code it doesn't work. I really don't understand why, just empty portlet without any text messages. 

P.S. Why we must override not render() method but doView() ?

This code seems to be very easy and I get sooo frustrated :/

Comment: Be sure that the default view configured in portlet.xml file is the jsp you wrote. `doView`is where the portlet get initialized.

Comment: I have this line : `<value>/view.jsp</value>`  and my .jsp file is also named view.jsp. I suppose there is no problem with it?

Comment: There is no problem, but your  `view.jsp` must be located under `webapp` folder. Is this the case ?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!! That's exactly what I need! I'll give you as much reputation as I can

P.S. It seems I cant give even 1 rep. :/

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you are not obliged to put all your jsp directly under `/webapp`. You can create a folder, `views` for example, under `webapp`in which put your jsp. But in the `portlet.xml` file, you must configure view by giving the full path starting from `webapp` folder. In the given example, it must be `/views/view.jsp`

Comment: For the reputation, you are limited to 30 per day. May be you used them.